# personemail not showing in account permission set

Tags: email, account, fields, permission-sets

when tring to set permissions for account fields for a permission set, personemail is not showing,
how can I update the field permission using permission sets and not profiles?

Answer (score 2):

PersonEmail is the Email field of the contact, and it’s only available for PersonAccounts. You have to refer always to contact fields for all PersonFields in Account.